# Sublime eslint plugin: "Unable to resolve path to module" while the path exist

Tags: sublimetext, reactjs, eslint

In my .jsx module I get this error

> Unable to resolve path to module

How can I fix it? The imported module exist.

[image: Screenshot of Sublime showing the code and error messahe]

I use [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import), github issue [here](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/139)

Comment: Do you get the same error report when you run eslint from the command line? Which eslint Plugin do you use? Please add it to your post by editing.

Comment: $eslint app/routes.jsx handles without errors, eslint-plugin-import.

Comment: How did you go with this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I could not resolve this issue, relative paths still show warnings

Comment: Also having the same issue - if I find a solution, I'll share it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that eslint-import doesn't automatically include the `.jsx` extension. You can try this:

Add to your .eslintrc:

```json
"settings": {
  "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
}
```

If just that doesn't help, try to add [eslint-import-resolver-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-webpack) as a devDependency.

`npm i -D eslint-import-resolver-webpack`

And include it in the .eslintrc settings:

```json
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": "webpack",
  "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
}
```

You may need to configure the "module roots" in webpack:

```js
resolve: {
  modules: ['app', 'node_modules']
}
```

You might need to replace `modules` by `root` in webpack 1.x.

If it still don't work (and it does in command line), it might be a sublime linter issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import#sublimelinter-eslint