# error Unable to resolve path to module 'html-webpack-plugin' import/no-unresolved

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, bundler

I am getting this error

```bash
/home/runner/work/toDoList/toDoList/webpack.config.js
  2:35  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'html-webpack-plugin'  import/no-unresolved
```

on my linters run by GitHub actions.

I do not get this error when I run eslint locally; this only happens in GitHub actions. These solutions did not work for me.

- [How to manually add a path to be resolved in eslintrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769880/how-to-manually-add-a-path-to-be-resolved-in-eslintrc)
- [Using eslint with typescript - Unable to resolve path to module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198502/using-eslint-with-typescript-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module)
- [eslint / typescript: Unable to resolve path to module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199506/eslint-typescript-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module)
- [Why I got error Unable to resolve path to module? Eslint with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66273491/why-i-got-error-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module-eslint-with-typescript)
- [Sublime eslint plugin: "Unable to resolve path to module" while the path exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230925/sublime-eslint-plugin-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module-while-the-path-exist)

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: './dist',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And my `.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb-base"],
  "rules": {
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "eol-last": "off",
    "import/extensions": [ 1, {
      "js": "always", "json": "always"
    }]
  },
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "dist/",
    "build/"
  ]
}
```

Here is the [pull request with error](https://github.com/shasherazi/toDoList/pull/1) if I'm missing something.

Comment: You should install the modules before running eslint `npm install`

Comment: You're right. The `html-webpack-plugin` wasn't getting installed in the GitHub actions environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my `html-webpack-plugin` wasn't getting installed in the GitHub actions environment because it wasn't in `linters.yml` file. Adding `npm install html-webpack-plugin` in `linters.yml` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@shasherazi is right, in my case I added it like below under eslint
`run: | npm install html-webpack-plugin`
just before the eslint install command in `linters.yml` file

Answer (score 0):

"npm install html-webpack-plugin" is added to the linter file as in the picture

[image: "npm install html-webpack-plugin" is added to the linter file as in the picture]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.